# A minimalistic Python\Java library for HOSTING WMS content

Tags: python, wms, software-recommendations, java, xyz

Colleagues of mine have developed an algorithm that, given a bunch of parameters, outputs a colormap. The initial version was integrated as a QGIS plugin. However now we need to create an ArcGIS Enterprise service out of it.

I have no experience with ArcGIS and little so with QGIS but my basic knowledge in this area tells me that the easiest way to do that is via WMS since all that is required is:

- **Input** - the front-end in ArcGIS generates the parameters (via buttons, drop-down menus and what not) and sends those to the backend
- **Output** - the back-end processes the data and returns e.g. a PNG colormap that can be added as a layer

The output does not need to be interacted with any further so WFS is not really required here.

Both QGIS and ArcGIS support WMS. So far I have gained some experience with setting up GeoServer as well as using some of its features (WMS incl.) and I've also read a little bit about MapServer. Both solutions enjoy good support and popularity, however for my use case they seem to provide too much and also the system requirements are not really optimal for building a slim web service.

I am looking for a Python\Java library for serving (**NOT retrieving**) WMS content. Any WMS-compatible client should be able to retrieve such data (given that it supports the WMS version that is exposed), e.g. Leaflet, QGIS, ArcGIS etc.

PS: If no such library exists, XYZTiles serving should also be an option.

Comment: To provide a WMS service, you need a (server) application, not a library. MapServer and GeoServer are examples of such applications. There may be libraries available that can help you *build* your own WMS server application, but a library by itself does not do anything. A tile server is another possibility, if you're okay with a fixed number of zoom levels. You could use some application to pre-render all tiles, and serve those on a webserver. In that case, have a look at WMTS.

Comment: You could look at GeoTools (Open Source Java GIS Toolkit) which is the library used by GeoServer.

Comment: It sounds like what you actually need is a WPS - GeoServer (Java) or PyWPS (python) would be my starting points

Comment: @Berend With library I meant something that gives me the means to create a server, which specializes in WMS content. Sorry for the incorrectly used term.

Comment: I can't see a reason not to use MapServer of GeoServer. In the end, an application that you write yourself will still need to do the same heavy lifting, i.e. converting some geodata into an image. And as far as I can remember, MapServer isn't *that* heavy. If that's not what you want, you could also look into using a cloud service that offers MapServer hosting. Or you could use SVG, or a PDF containing vector graphics.